Learning material for R
I am looking for learning material for R (including base R & tidyverse approaches (with a focus on readr, dplyr & tidyr)) and data visualisation using ggplot2 library for commercial teaching purposes. Bonus point if it includes data.table approach.
My company uses Software Carpentry content at the moment, and I want to explore other options. Open-access content is preferred.

Flagged since this question is likely to be opinion-based. That said, in case someone comes here trying to learn R, there's a great R package called Swirl that teaches R hands-on in RStudio, with good instruction on installing R.

One resource is big book of r which according to the website is a collection of over 300 books written with content related to R. The books range from learning R to developing software using R but also include books on applications where the main programming language is R.
You should check it out.

Thank you René!
